# How running a program or PowerShell script, after the "SQL Server Maintenance" plan ended?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, maintenance-plan

I need to execute/launch a PowerShell script after my maintenance plan did some work on my database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run your `PowerShell` script within `SQL Server 2008/2008r2/2012 Agent`. In SQL Server Management Studio create a SQL job and select a `PowerShell job step` specifying the full path to your PowerShell script. Then add the job at the end of your maintenance plan as '`Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task`'